# How do I format a JSON response using python?

Tags: json, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

**This is my JSON data:**

```
data = [{"document_id":"FT_3860001798686","party_type":"1","name":"LEE, GABRIEL"},{"document_id":"FT_3860001798686","party_type":"1","name":"MORRISON, VERNA"},{"document_id":"FT_3860001798686","party_type":"2","name":"PIONEER S&L ASSOCIATION"}]
```

**Expected O/P:**

```
data = {"document_id":"FT_3860001798686", "party 1":"1", "name":["LEE, GABRIEL", "MORRISON, VERNA"],"party 2":"2", "name":["PIONEER S&L ASSOCIATION"]}
```

Suppose if any party_type dnt have any value need to display that value as N/A, like below

```
data = {"document_id":"FT_3860001798686", "party 1":"1", "name":["LEE, GABRIEL", "MORRISON, VERNA"], "party 2":"2", "name": "N/A"}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote as your **Expected O/P** is not possible, because you can not have two elements with the same key ("name" in your sample) in a dictionary.